# How to overload constructors in JavaScript ECMA6?

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-6, overloading, constructor-overloading

### Objective

Implement a mechanism to allow constructor overload in JavaScript ECMA6

### Why this is not a duplicate

The topic [Why doesn't JavaScript ES6 support multi-constructor classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626524/why-javascript-es6-doesnt-have-multi-constructor-class), although similar is not the same as this one. The other topic merely focuses on a constructor overloading using the **old** ECMAScript versions, while this topic focuses on ECMA6. If you are looking for an updated answer, this is the place.

### Background

I have a JavaScript class with a given constructor, and I want the user to be able to have different constructors when instantiating an object. An example of what I pretend could be the following:

```
const DEFAULT_WHEEL_NUMBER = 4;
const DEFAULT_COLOR = "black";    
const DEFAULT_NAME = "myCar";

class Car{

    constructor(numberWheels, aName, aColor){
        this.wheelsNum = numberWheels;
        this.name = aName;
        this.color = aColor;
    }

    constructor(aName){
        this(DEFUALT_WHEEL_NUMBER, aName, DEFAULT_COLOR);
    }

    constructor(){
        this(DEFUALT_WHEEL_NUMBER, DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_COLOR);
    }
}
```

In this code, the user has three constructors he can use, each one taking a different amount of parameters. An usage example follows:

```
var car1 = new Car(3, "tricicle-car", "white");
var car2 = new Car("Opel"); //creates black car with 4 wheels called Opel
var car3 = new Car(); //creates a black car, with 4 wheels called myCar
```

### Problem

This is a straightforward example if one is using Java or C#, because those languages have constructor overloads.

However, from the [documentation on classes from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) one can conclude that JavaScript does not.

### Question

1. Is there a way to implement a similar mechanism for JavaScript classes using ECMA6? If not, what is the best/closest alternative?

Comment: Take a look at this very similar question: [Why JavaScript ES6 doesn't have multi-constructor class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626524/why-javascript-es6-doesnt-have-multi-constructor-class)

Comment: I think the ultimate problem is that Javascript just isn't Java and mimicking Java idioms leads to a lot of trouble in general. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: A great question if you actually think that overloading is a good idea. Your example screams "Builder".

Comment: @zeroflagL: perhaps you could be kind enough to provide an answer with an example? I am a fan of patterns !

Comment: Take a look to TypeScript. They use typed objects, like `object: int`

Comment: what about using the "typeof"??

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no in-built solution for this in JavaScript. An alternative solution can be using the `arguments` object (in some cases), or passing your own configuration options, similar to this:

```
const defaults = {
    numberWheels: 4,
    color: "black",   
    name: "myCar"
}

class Car {
    constructor(options) {
         this.wheelsNum = options.numberWheels || defaults.numberWheels;
         this.name = options.name || defaults.name;
         this.color = options.color || defaults.color;
    }
}
```

This is basically the old school solution, I use the same logic in ES3.

Comment: Instead of the `arguments` object you can use `...restParameters`, which gives you a real array.

Comment: When using `||` operator, you should put `options` parameter first, because otherwise you will always get the default object.

Comment: whoops, true :) updated it, thanks

Answer (score 23):

You're right (as far as I know) that this isn't a feature JavaScript classes support. My recommendation here, since you're already making use of ES6 features, would be to make use of [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) instead:

```
class Car {
    constructor(numberWheels = 4, aName = "myCar", aColor = "black"){
        this.wheelsNum = numberWheels;
        this.name = aName;
        this.color = aColor;
    }
}
```

This obviously comes with the caveat that you can't have 'overloads' with different parameter orders like you do in your example (although in my opinion, that's a good thing - a consistent API is much nicer to work with).

meskobalazs's answer is also a good option, especially if you have a lot of options that you want your object to take in. Doing that through function params like this can get a bit messy!